# Bootstrap : align button addons over multiple rows

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

One of the form I'm creating is to add contact information for a given supplier. The part of the form is dynamic and looks like this

[image]

But, as you can see, the dropdown buttons are dynamically resized to fit the content. I thought using some kind of table layout, but I'm afraid that will not play nice with Bootstrap's CSS.

Bottom line is, has anyone done this before, and what was your solution?

Comment: If your problem are just those three buttons or you know the longest text you can use a fixed width for all.

Comment: The application is localized and the max length of the options is, thus, undefined. A naïve solution would be to give it a "safe" width, but the app is also used on mobile devices... I'd like to save space if I can :)

Comment: The issue is that this is the intended functionality of dropdown-input-addons. A table layout would work where the first cell contains the dropdown and the next contains the `<input>`, but people seem to hate table layouts. Last alternative is using the grid system, have a `col-*-2` for your dropdown and a `col-*-8` for the input and a `col-*-2` for the trashcan button.

Comment: That's a nice aproach @TimLewis I will suggest the "table" layout if you don't need any responsive for each data but the `col` aproach is also pretty nice

Comment: I'm making an example to show it in action, gimme one sec :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comments, there's a number of different approaches. First, using a table:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
          Phone
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Cell</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Office</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Fax</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
          Cell
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Phone</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Office</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Fax</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
          Business Fax
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Phone</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Office</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Cell</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Second using the Grid System:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
          Phone
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Fax</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Office</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Cell</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
          Cell
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Phone</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Office</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Fax</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
          Business Fax
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Phone</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Office</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Cell</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's a bootply with the live example:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/XROIXl2zwr)

Hope that gives you some insight! You can also try custom CSS if you just want the buttons to be the same width, but you'd have to know the length of each segment of text first, which my be tricky.

**Edit**

I should also note, putting a `<table>` inside a container (modal, panel, conatiner, container-fluid, ect) will make it conform to that container's max width, so the table doesn't have to be full screen.

Comment: From your second example, I came up with [this](http://www.bootply.com/KiTHyPi82k). It's simple and follows the layout I have so far. What do you think?

Comment: That's an interesting approach, but it looks good; nice and aligned :) Remember to take a look at smaller sizes too, the right-aligned buttons with left-aligned options gets a bit squished outside the screen.